# Minimax solution not working

Tags: python

So I've been looking at this problem for a very long time now. But I just can't figure it out.

I have got a player class that looks like this:

```
class perfectplayer():
    def __init__(self, player, game):
        self.player = player
        self.game = game

    def possible_moves(self, board):
        '''Finds all possible moves of given board'''
        possible_moves = []
        for x in range(len(board)):
            for y in range(len(board[x])):
                if board[x][y] is None:
                    possible_moves.append((x, y))
        return possible_moves

    def score(self, game, depth):
        '''Gives score to given board based on depth and who wins'''
        if game.win()[0]:
            if game.win()[1] is self.player:
                return 10 - depth
            else:
                return depth - 10
        return 0

    def minimax(self, game, depth):
        '''Constructs minimax tree and selects best move based on that tree'''
        if game.game_over():
            return self.score(game, depth)
        depth += 1
        scores = []
        moves = []

        # Recursively creates tree of possible decisions 
        for move in self.possible_moves(game.board):
            possible_game = game
            possible_game.move(move)
            scores.append(self.minimax(possible_game, depth))
            moves.append(move)

        # max the score if it is player's turn
        if game.current_player is self.player:
            max_score_idx = scores.index(max(scores))
            self.choice = moves[max_score_idx]
            return scores[max_score_idx]
        # min the score if it is not player's turn
        else:
            min_score_idx = scores.index(min(scores))
            self.choice = moves[min_score_idx]
            return scores[min_score_idx]

    def best_move(self, game):
        '''returns best move in give game state'''
        self.minimax(game, 0)
        return self.choice
```

Which hooks into a game class that has all the required functions to work properly. It can return if a game is over, who won it and who's currently going to move. This all works as I have tested it. The idea is basically that the best_move function returns the next choice for the AI-player. But when I run my little game:

```
game1 = game()
player1 = perfectplayer("x", game1)

while not game1.game_over():
    # finds best choice
    choice = player1.best_move(game1)
    # puts down a mark
    game1.move(choice)
    # renders game
    game1.render()
    move_x = int(input("please input row: "))
    move_y = int(input("please input column: "))
    game1.move((move_x, move_y))
    if game1.win()[0]:
        print(game1.win()[1], "has won!")
```

I get this output:

```
>> o|o|x|
   o|x|o|
   x|o|x|
>> please input row: 1
>> please input column: 1
>> x has won!
```

So it correctly knows that x has won and it properly asks for my input, but why is my game board filled up after 1 turn? Where in my code does this happen? The choice variable is correct as it is always a tuple of two coordinates.

The pseudo-code is from this website: https://www.neverstopbuilding.com/blog/minimax

Here is the code for the game class:

```
class game():
    def __init__(self, board=None, starting_player="x"):
        if board is None:
            self.board = [[None, None, None],
                          [None, None, None],
                          [None, None, None]]
        else:
            self.board = board
        self.current_player = starting_player

    def render(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                if item is None:
                    print(".", end="|")
                else:
                    print(item, end="|")
            print()

    def move(self, move):
        move_x = move[0]
        move_y = move[1]
        self.board[move_x][move_y] = self.current_player
        self.switch()

    def legalmove(self, move):
        move_x = move[0]
        move_y = move[1]
        if self.board[move_x][move_y] is None:
            return True
        return False

    def switch(self):
        if self.current_player == "x":
            self.current_player = "o"
        else:
            self.current_player = "x"

    def win(self):
        board = self.board
        for x in range(len(board)):
            for y in range(len(board[x])):
                if board[0][y] == board[1][y] == board[2][y] is not None:
                    return True, board[0][y]
                if board[x][0] == board[x][1] == board[x][2] is not None:
                    return True, board[x][0]
                if x == y and board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] is not None:
                    return True, board[0][0]
                if x + y == 2 and board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] is not None:
                    return True, board[0][2]
        return False, None

    def game_over(self):
        for x in range(len(self.board)):
            for y in range(len(self.board[x])):
                if self.board[x][y] is None:
                    return False
        return True
```

Comment: Can you put `game` class? Without it anyone will be unable to run your code.

Comment: have done now :)

Comment: BTW, you should use names beginning with an uppercase letter for classes. Currently you're using `game` both for the class and the instance, which is confusing to read and can lead to errors. Similarly, you've used `possible_moves` for a method name, and  list in that method. That won't hurt anything, but it is confusing. Of course, it _would_ make a mess if the `possible_moves` method were recursive.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Have refactored a bit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that this line:

```
possible_game = game
```

Does *not* create a copy of the game's state, but merely another reference to it. So your search modifies the actual board. To fix this, you could either:

- Implement an 'undo' operation to undo a move after exploring the resulting state.
- or implement a copy operation for game states.

Comment: How would a copy operation look like?

Comment: Something along the lines of `def copy(self): return copy.deepcopy(self)` - note that you have to `import copy` for this to work